# How to change the type on the xaxis so that it is discontinuous

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to plot the following on a python bar plot:

```
x-axis = [417, 1250, 2500, 4167, 5833, 7500, 10000, 14167, 20833, 29167, 32500, 37500, 45833, 50000, 54167, 62500, 70000, 75000, 90000, 100000, 110000, 250000]
y-axis = [3.6342769701606734, 5.623565416985462, 17.17674062739097, 18.74521805661821, 16.985462892119358, 12.586074980872228, 1.0328997704667175, 17.17674062739097, 3.978576893649579, 0.8033664881407804, 0.11476664116296864, 0.3825554705432288, 0.42081101759755163, 0.26778882938026016, 0.03825554705432287, 0.11476664116296864, 0.42081101759755163, 0.03825554705432287, 0.1530221882172915, 0.1912777352716144, 0.03825554705432287, 0.07651109410864575]
```

I used the following line:
`fig = plt.bar(l1, l2, color = "red", align = "center")`
I get the following graph:
[image]

I'm wondering how I get rid of the empty space in the middle. So my biggest two x-values are 110000 and 250000. However, looking at my bar graph I have continuous values between those numbers. Is there a way to get rid of that dead space? Can I somehow change the x-values to be categorical values instead of continuous values?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
plt.bar([str(n) for n in x], y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Just give the *x* values as strings, and the plot becomes categorical.
Of course this approach doesn't scale well for a large number of "categories"... here the number of data points is just 22, but to get a readable figure I have to intervene to modify the defaults:

1. I have rotated the tick labels, that otherwise were overlapping and unreadable, and
2. I have  used `plt.tight_layout()`, to make space for the now vertical tick labels, that otherwise were truncated at the lower edge of the figure.

Comment: @tdy Not only `'' % n` was less idiomatic, it was wrong — it was a typo for `'%d"%n` :-( ፨ now I have corrected it accepting your suggestion, thank you.